# where does git server stores the pushed files and from where it fetches when it's cloned on client?

Tags: git, git-server

I am trying to understand how git client server model works. But one thing is not clear for me when we push the files from the client machine in many sources it's said that the files are pushed to server machine. But when I searched for the pushed file on server they are not found. According to doumentation server's bare repository only used for colloborating multiple git users as common point. But, my question is when new git user wants to pull the project for the first time from where does the server serves it?

Please help me in understanding this concept. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The files are pushed and stored in the form of Git objects, same way they’re stored in the `.git` directory in the local repository you push from.

Comment: "But when I searched for the pushed file on server they are not found." - seems a bit unclarified. For starters, if the file is "in" the repo (on any branch), how it's stored in only an implementation detail. Or what the "pushed file" just "not found" in the repo? (What is currently in the Working Copy has *no bearing* on the content of the repository.)

Comment: I want to know where(in which path) the pushed file gets stored on server, like bare repository or somewhere else(some other path)?

Comment: Git stores *commits* rather than files. The commits themselves *contain* files, but in a sense, there are no files at all, there are only commits. Extracting a commit, through Git's index, into a work-tree, is how you convert the stored commit to a set of files.

Comment: fine, but are commits(files) are stored on server's bare repository? if yes in what form they are stored? and when we clone the repository to a client machine from where does the commits are fetched?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know where(in which path) the pushed file gets stored on server, like bare repository or somewhere else(some other path)?

A [bare repo](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) includes only the [`.git` usual content](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/sitaramc/sitaramc.github.com/blob/dce410b2a2804723676db9cabd7bb506b6d9ba05/concepts/bare.html) and no working tree (which usually shows the actual files of a given commits)

The [objects subfolder](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) will include your files (blob) compressed, but also your trees and commits

[image: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/data-model-3.png]

Depending on the [transfer protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) those pack files are transfered back to your own `.git` repo, and one commit is checkout in your repo working tree.